# Как убрать анимацию вращения у Progress bar?

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток, необходимо на круглом progress bar отображать рейтинг заведения. Т.е без анимации вращения.
Подскажите как это реализовать, а то я уже все перепробовал?

Comment: Можете реализовать свою разметку и создать свой кастомный alertDialog, в котором подцепите ее через layoutInflater. После чего в начале загрузки будете вызывать диалог методом show(), a убирать через dismiss();

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Вопрос совсем не про диалог, вроде как.

Answer (score 0):

Такого параметра у круглого прогресс бара нет. Но вы можете притвориться горизонтальным прогрессом и установить круглый вид для `progressDrawable`, описанный в xml примерно так:

**progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="4dp"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <solid
            android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Сам ProgressBar в разметке:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="66"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Вижу как минимум 2 способа решения:

1) Тупой: вписываем прогрессбар в `RelativeLayout` и сверху крутилки впихиваем картинку.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        android:clickable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2) Применяем кастомный [ProgressBar](https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar) с картинкой посередине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]